# Spring aws-cloud SNS http end point confirm subscription not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

In my spring boot aws-cloud SNS http end point confirm subscription is not working. When SNS confirmation comes following error coming in my application.
Error :

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract void org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.endpoint.NotificationStatus.confirmSubscription() is no accessor method!] with root cause
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract void org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.endpoint.NotificationStatus.confirmSubscription() is no accessor method!
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.spring
```

My controller handler is  :

```
     @NotificationSubscriptionMapping
        public void handleSubscriptionMessage( NotificationStatus status)   throws IOException {
            //Confirming SNS subscription
            status.confirmSubscription();
        }
```

My Pom contains following :

```
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Spring AWS autoconfiguration-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I followed the explanation in this [link](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_annotation_driven_http_notification_endpoint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you specify the custom resolver:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <ref bean="notificationResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<aws-messaging:notification-argument-resolver id="notificationResolver" />
```

Also, I cannot see the controller mapping, but in tutorial there is a statement:

> Currently it is not possible to define the mapping URL on the method
>   level therefore the RequestMapping must be done at type level and must
>   contain the full path of the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @m.aibin .... I am doing this using spring boot. Will the 'spring-cloud-autoconfigure' handle this ? Controller mapping I defined on class level. It is working fine as the request comes to handleSubscriptionMessage method.

Comment: I didn't specify custom resolver. How can I do this in java config way ? As I am using spring boot.

Comment: http://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2013/02/13/spring-app-migration-from-xml-to-java-based-config/

Comment: Hi. I have managed to add this using xml itself as the java config way has some issue while overriding request resolvers.But now I get some error while confirming request. Where/How should I configure the topic ARN in spring aws cloud ? I could not find anything on the tutorial though.

Comment: My issue got resolved. Resolver worked perfect. Another issue was that I dint  configure region.

Comment: Any chance you can post some code on how you resolved this issue. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Putting this out for anyone who is after java config for this. Please note you have to use NotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver which implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.endpoint.NotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver notificationResolver;

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(notificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }

    @Bean
    public NotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver notificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver () {

        return new NotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Kotlin Configuration looks like this, to configure the subscription and messaging and un-subscription method argument resolving

```
        import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
        import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.endpoint.config.NotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverConfigurationUtils
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
        import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer
        
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebMvc
        class ListenerWebConfiguration : WebMvcConfigurer
        {
          @Autowired
          private lateinit var amazonSNS: AmazonSNS
        
          override fun addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers: MutableList<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>) {
argumentResolvers.add(NotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverConfigurationUtils.getNotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(amazonSNS))
          }
        }
```